# Titanium Android module: crop, rotate, resize... image

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Do you know a Titanium Android module that allows to edit, rotate, resize... image, like this?

[Android resize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlIaN.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is the camera.action.CROP:

```
//STARTS CROPPING INTENT
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(savedPicture), "image/*");
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PICTURE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (requestCode == CROP_PICTURE)
   {
    // SAVE PICTURE TO FILESYSTEM
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap croppedPicture = extras.getParcelable("data");
    File pictureFolder = RouterApplication.getInstance().getPictureDirectory();
    File picture = null;
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    try
     {
      picture = new File(pictureFolder, "a.jpg");

      if (croppedPicture != null)
       {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(picture);
        croppedPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut);

       }
     }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I tried it on Titanium using the Android intent. This is the code I used:  [Titanium working code](http://ctrlv.it/javascript/6212/1237089225)
It seems to work for Android versions <6. But on Android 6 (API = 23) I get this error:  [Android 6 error](http://ctrlv.it/txt/6209/2878359207)

Comment: You have to save the media first to media storage. Anyway thanks for the downvote...
Try to be more spesific with your questions

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried to save the file on my device, and then use the crop intent. But it displays the same error... it is as if the uri was wrong, but the uri is correct. The strange thing is that only happens on Android API 23. I also added the permits access to memory and camera...
PS: I have not put any downvote, someone put -1 to my question...

Comment: Wich version of Titanium do you use? API 23 needs Titanium SDK Version 5.1.0.
Is it possible to change the line `var imageData = param.intent.getBlobExtra("data");` to `param.intent.getData()`

I also don't know how it works in titanium but in android you receive an uri not an image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try. I use Ti 5.2.2 SDK